# Email me every time someone makes a contribution

Tags: civicontribute, email

I've made a contributions page with CiviCRM on my site. How can I configure CiviCRM to send me an email anytime anyone makes a donation, please?

(I know I can have Civi send me a report of recent contributions periodically, but that doesn't solve this case. I want to configure Civi to send me an email with info about a single donation immediately, when the donation is made.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have it set to email a receipt to the contributor you can have that receipt bcc'd to you.

In Manage Contribution at the bottom of the receipt tab page is the option to cc or bcc someone.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a more complicated workflow you could also use the CiviRules extension.

That way you could send an email to a backoffice manager when certain criteria are met and when other criteria are met you could send it to another backoffice manager.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a profile in use on the contribution page, you can configure the profile to send a notification whenever it gets submitted.